# CoreML: exception Espresso exception: "Invalid state": Null output blobs

Tags: ios, keras, coreml, coremltools

I run a keras model inside my iOS application using **CoreML** and I have this problem I can't completely understand but I think it's not related to the app but instead to the Keras model. I'm using 48x48 images, is it supported this size in CoreML?

> [Espresso::handle_ex_plan] exception=Espresso exception: "Invalid state": Null output blobs [Exception from Layer: 5: sequential/conv2d_3/BiasAdd]

> 2020-12-15 01:06:31.245711+0100 TSD[41213:1753543] [coreml] Error
> computing NN outputs -1

> 2020-12-15 01:06:31.245849+0100 TSD[41213:1753543] [coreml] Failure in
> -executePlan:error:. Error computing NN outputs.

```
def cnn_model():
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(CLASSNAME_SIZE, activation='softmax'))
return model
```

**EDIT 1**

This is the problematic layer according to the error description (conv2d_3/biasadd)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would remove this line,

```
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(X.shape[1])))
```

from your Keras model and try again. Anything else seems fine, but that line might be messing things up during the model conversion to Core ML.

Comment: Removing x.shape[1] also reduced the precision in the prediction stage

Comment: OK, that's good to know. :-) I can't really see anything else that is obviously wrong. At this point I'd use a tool such as Netron to look at the actual mlmodel to see if anything is out of place.

Comment: Alright can I send it a screenshot once I look at the model in Netron?

Comment: Edited the question with the Netron screenshot

Comment: Just because Core ML says the error happens on a certain layer doesn't necessarily make it true. ;-) I would try the model up to that layer (by removing the layer and everything after). If that works OK, I would try it including that layer. If that still works OK, I would add in all the remaining layers one-by-one until you get the error. The last layer you added is the one with the actual problem.